# Parse batch query returns empty array

Tags: json, rest, parse-platform, batch-processing

I am trying to perform a batch query using Parse's REST API to delete a batch of objects. As far as I can tell the query is going through with no errors, but all I am getting for a response is an empty array `[]`.

This is my JSON object that I am passing to the url: https://api.parse.com/1/batch

```
{"requests": [
    {
        "method": "DELETE",
        "path": "/1/classes/Contact/YYmT4fbBoo"
    }
]}
```

Why is this happening? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an actual object in the Contact class with the OBJECTID you are sending it. Can you confirm whether or not it is actually deleted?

"The response from batch will be a list with the same number of elements as the input list. Each item in the list with be a dictionary with either the success or error field set. The value of success will be the normal response to the equivalent REST command"

An empty array in the response could indicate that the request did not affect any objects.

Comment: The OBJECTID that I threw in there was simply for example purposes. I made an update to the my question with the real object ID. I am using a PUT batch query else where in my application and that works just fine, and I am receiving the Success messages that you speak of.

Comment: I'm still wondering whether the object you are trying to delete actually exists. And if it does, does it get deleted in the db?

Comment: The object does actually exist, I just double checked the name of the objectId. No it does not get deleted. During the action the database remains unchanged.

[According the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest#objects-deleting) I should at least get an error if the object does not exist.